# R: looping through data.frame columns

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I got a following my_data:

```
        geneid chr     acc_no start   end size strand   S1   S2   A1   A2
1 gene_010010   1 AC12345.1  3662  4663 1002      -  328  336  757  874
2 gene_010020   1 AC12345.1  5750  7411 1662      -  480  589  793  765
3 gene_010030   2 AC12345.1  9003 11024 2022      -  653  673  875  920
4 gene_010040   2 AC12345.1 12006 12566  561      -  573  623  483  430
5 gene_010050   3 AC12345.1 15035 17032 1998      - 2256 2333 1866 1944
6 gene_010060   3 AC12345.1 18188 18937  750      -  526  642  650  586
```

I am able to calculate sums for a given column, i.e:

```
chr.sums <- data.frame(with (my_data, tapply(S1, INDEX=chr, FUN=sum)))
```

Problem is, I want to get chr.sums with four columns (S1, S2, A1 and A2) and 30 rows corresponding to unique chr numbers. I do not want to switch to Python back and forth, but looping through columns and assigning output to specific columns in data.frame baffles me.

**EDIT**
Toy data set above.

Comment: Please use `dput(my_data)` and paste the results into your question.  This will mean we can post a solution using your actual data.

Comment: @Andrie: I got 8k rows in my_data which I guess is too much for a question. Flipping chr numbers for rows 4-6 to 2 will create a toy set.

Comment: In that case, construct a toy subset and post that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ddply` from `plyr`. Here is some code:

```
plyr::ddply(my_data, .(chr), summarize, S1 = sum(S1), S2 = sum(S2), 
  A1 = sum(A1), A2 = sum(A2))
```

EDIT. A more compact solution would be:

```
plyr::ddply(my_data, .(chr), colwise(sum, .(S1, S2, A1, A2)))
```

Here is how it works. The data is first split into pieces based on `chr`. Then, the columns `S1, S2, A1, A2` are summed up for each piece. Finally, they are assembled back into a single data frame.

Any place you have this kind of a `split-apply-combine` problem, think `plyr` as a solution.

Comment: i was just typing the `colwise` solution.

Comment: +1 Nice use of `colwise`.  Even better would be `ddply(my_data[, -(3:7)], .(chr), colwise, sum)`

Comment: @Ramnath: Thanks a lot, it works as expected. Saved me a lot of time. I will look into plyr.

Comment: @Andrie: thanks. For a R newbie Ramnath answer is bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`tapply` won't handle multiple columns but the formula version of `aggregate` will.

```
chr.sums <- aggregate(cbind(S1,S2,A1,A2) ~ chr, data = my_data, FUN=sum)))
```

Comment: thank you. chr.sums <- aggregate(cbind(S1,S2,A1,A2) ~ chr, data = my_data, FUN=sum) works.